# Professor and department evaluation system ERD

Tags: sql, csv, erd

I created a ERD (dont know if correct) but the real problem is all about CSV file
as you can see guys I have three tables, Student(top left corner), teacher(3rd from top left) and course table(2nd from top) now our system can upload a CSV file for proff and student the problem is I dont know how to upload a file for course that has a relation for tables(proff and stud).

[image: unreadable hand-drawn ERD :(]

Comment: SO uses Markdown, not BBCode. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: upload how? are you writing code? what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to Bulk-Load CSV files to tables with foreign key constraints.

See this question and accepted Answer

[How to use BULK INSERT when rows depend on foreign keys values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380621/how-to-use-bulk-insert-when-rows-depend-on-foreign-keys-values)

Comment: I just cant imagine how I will store data for course table without using csv?, I will only rely data on two tables(stud,prof) do you recommend to recreate the erd. all I wanted is to have a simple student - teacher with course table relationship. Please I do really need an answer :/