# How to insert excel data into foreign key table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, oledb, sqlbulkcopy

I want to insert data from excel sheet to multiple tables i used sqlbulk to insert data in 1 table. tables are linked with foriegn keys. first data will be inserted in parent table after that data will go in child table.

[My Excel Sheet Image](http://postimg.org/image/qq4928wmr/):
[image: https://s5.postimg.org/yvmb0ekvr/Untitled.png]

[Relational Diagram](http://postimg.org/image/jlmft7pdf/):
[image: https://s5.postimg.org/h4aoly5h3/Products.png]

My Question is how can i insert excel data into different tables from parent to child. I mean First data will go in Category Table then Sub-Category Table, then Brand Table, then Model table and at last Products_Info table.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Sorry. but i don't know where to start from. i am begineer. :(

Comment: Then maybe this task is beyond you, and you need to get help from someone on your team. [so] isn't a place to come to have your work done for you, or to educate you on how to do things which are outside of your current reach.

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk insert your initial data into a staging table. Then use a series of statements to create your data in each lookup table.

[How to use BULK INSERT when rows depend on foreign keys values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380621/how-to-use-bulk-insert-when-rows-depend-on-foreign-keys-values)

Another tool in the MSSQL platform is SQL Server Integration Services, a more robust ETL tool. You're describing a scenario where the Lookup Task really shines. 
[SSIS Lookup Task](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/SMcDonald/bidn-blog/621/ssis-lookup-task)

Comment: I can't use ETL tool because excel file will be uploaded to server then i need to read excel file through oledb connection and insert values into tables.